# How to statically link NetCDF in Fortran Executable

Tags: fortran, static-libraries, gfortran, netcdf

I'm trying to use NetCDF in a Fortran executable that then gets sent out to a lot of machines for parallel computation, so I need it to be statically linked. I'm doing the compiling on my own machine with mpif90, but I've also tried gfortran (Linux, though could also use Windows).

I'd love to build something entirely static, but packaging mpiexec in a static library seems difficult.

Here's a sketch of what I'm doing:

```
mpif90 -c -o somestuff.o somestuff.f90
mpif90 -c -o thing_that_uses_netCDF.o thing_that_uses_netCDF.f90 \
  -I/usr/include -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lnetcdff
ar cr libintermediate.a thing_that_uses_netCDF.o somestuff.o
mpif90 -c -o downstreamstuff.o downstreamstuff.f90 \
  -I./path/to/intermediatelib -L./path/to/intermediatelib -lintermediate \
  -I/usr/include -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lnetcdff
mpif90 -o finalexecutable downstreamstuff.o \
  -I./path/to/intermediatelib -L./path/to/intermediatelib -lintermediate \
  -I/usr/include -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lnetcdff
```

Could someone walk me through linking the netcdff library? When I try it with gfortran if I use the -static flag I get "undefined reference to `__netcdf_MOD..." errors, though it compiles fine without the -static flag.

Thanks.

Comment: At which stage do you get the error? How does the exact command look like? Be aware that mpif90 is most likely the same gfortran, just with a few additional flags. Are you able to link it statically in some very simple test  example?

Comment: "sent out to a lot of machines for parallel computation, so I need it to be statically linked": it doesn't follow that using multiple machines means you must use static linking. If those machines all have access to the dynamic libraries you can continue to use dynamic linking as long as you set up your multi-machine environment correctly.

Comment: Let's eliminate the obvious.  Do you have libnetcdff.a and are you using the correct -L option to locate it?